# If the parent in a bridge is the root, is it a bridge cut node?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I am going through Professor Skiena's textbook and he says that there are 3 types of cut-nodes - root, bridge cut node, and parent cut node.

Now if the earliest reachable ancestor from a node is itself, it's parent and the node (if not leaf) become bridge cut nodes.

My question is that we have a simple 2-node undirected graph -> `A --- B`.

In this case, B's earliest reachable ancestor is B itself and hence A becomes the bridge cut node. However, I am unsure that should be the case; since if I delete A, even then B exists and the `num_components = 1`?

Comment: Could you give a more precise reference to what you're talking about than "[somewhere in] Professr Skiena's textbook"?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a graph that has only one vertex is `connected`.

That's to say if you delete `A`, the graph `B` is still connected. Clearly, `A` is not a cut-node because it can't disconnect the graph. So is vertex `B`.

A vertex is a parent/bridge cut-node *if and only if* it is not root vertex.

The concepts of these three types of cut-node are introduced by Skiena's in his own book, so these concepts are not very rigorous. An [errata list](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~skiena/algorist/book/errata) may be a good supplement.